# How would I create an event that triggers a landing page to pop up after a video stops playing?

Tags: javascript

I am a designer working with a client who wants his marketing video to play on his website and after the video is done playing it automatically sends you to a landing page.
(I have very limited javascript knowledge and hope to keep it as simple as possible)

Comment: It depends entirely on the implementation of the site.  If it's just a `<video/>` element, it might be as simple as listening for the [`ended`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event) event and routing after it has fired.  You need to add a [mre] for us to help you though.  Your question is too broad as it stands right now.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on the implementation of the site.  If it's just a `<video/>` element, it might be as simple as listening for the [`ended`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event) event and routing after it has fired.

Video in following snippet from MDN: [The Video Embed element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

```js
document.getElementById("test-video").addEventListener("ended", () => {
  console.log("Video ended do routing logic");
});
```

```html
<video id="test-video" autoplay muted controls width="250">
    <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm"
            type="video/webm">
    <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.mp4"
            type="video/mp4">
    Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
</video>
```